# Objective-c "multiple" getters and binding

Tags: objective-c, binding

I have a class that holds some information and one member is a property **options** (an NSUInteger). The individual bits of **options** should be accessible through property getters and setters, to be value-bound to checkboxes:

```
#define OP_CHAN_TAG   12

@interface MuxConfig: NSObject

@property NSUInteger options;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL opTagBlocks;

@end

@implementation MuxConfig

- (BOOL) isOpTagBlocks
{
  return (_options & (1 << OP_CHAN_TAG));
}

- (void) setOpTagBlocks:(BOOL)op
{
  if (op)
    _options |= (1 << OP_CHAN_TAG);
  else
    _options &= ~(1 << OP_CHAN_TAG);
}

@end
```

In this example, a checkbox has a value binding to **opTagBlocks** and an action handler to send the entire **options** property to a hardware device. This mechanism works. Another part of the application can receive the options from said device and stores them as one word into property **options**. And I was hoping that the checkbox(es) got updated but they don't. Obviously accessing property **options** does not 'trigger' the bitwise option handler(s).
So the big question is: how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to register dependent keys for your properties. Here is the documentation covering this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html

So in your example above, adding

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingOptions {

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"opTagBlocks",@"opTagWhatever",nil];
}
```

signals to the system that changes to `opTagBlocks` (and a second hypothetical property `opTagWhatever` to show how to add you other flags) also will change `options`.

You also need the reverse, and indicate that changes to `options` will also affect  `opTagBlocks`:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingOpTagBlocks {

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"options",nil];
}
```

Alternatively you could implement `+ keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`, see the above documentation.

Comment: Thanks Gerd, I read that documentation and it seems simple to understand, yet it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does `opTagBlocks` change when another bit of `options` changes?

Comment: In the above scenario there would be a notification for `opTagBlocks` when another bit in options changes. Obviously since the value did not really change the UI will not change, but it does trigger activity.

Comment: Why do you want this notification? Is registering dependent keys an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Got is working. It appears that

```
- (BOOL) isOpTagBlocks
{
  return (_options & (1 << OP_CHAN_TAG));
}
```

needed to be changed into:

```
- (BOOL) opTagBlocks
{
  return ((_options & (1 << OP_CHAN_TAG)) > 0);
}
```

Quite remarkable because the documentation says that boolean getters should start with "is" but this is not accepted by the KVO mechanism.
Regarding the returned value: checking against 0 is of course better but from the embedded world I live in, anything non-zero may be returned for a boolean result. Apparently not in Objective-C.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation saying that boolean getters should start with "is"? Does it say anything about the declaration of the property?